# How to read HTTP Response values from Visualforce correctly?

Tags: visualforce, httpresponse

I'm calling an external site from Visualforce and it's returning me a response as below (i.e. HttpResponse.GetBody() returned sting).

```
<DtResponse RequestId="" ResultCount="1" ErrorMessage=""> <Result TemporaryKey="**SecretTempKeyValue***==" /> </DtResponse>
```

I can read it by using string functions which is not a good method. I need to read this without using string functions. What is the best method to read the Temporary Key field in HTTP Response body?

Any help with a simple code example would be great. Thanks.

Comment: If the response is not in specific format then you have to read it through string function. If the response is in JSON or XML, you can use JASON parser or XML parser class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use getBodyDocument instead, which would look like this:

```
Dom.Document doc = response.getBodyDocument();
String tempKey = doc.getRootElement()
                  .getChildElement('Result', null)
                  .getAttribute('TemporaryKey', null);
```